# Terraform user data pass instance details

Tags: terraform

I need to set the host name & default network in the user data for my gcp instance with terraform, (user data template yml as below)

```
  serverInfo:
    serverId: 1
    hostname: ${hostname}
    defaultNetwork: ${defaultNetwork}
```

however, after some investigation I realized that this is quite difficult. As far as I understood, the user data is competed before the actual instance creation (correct me if wrong).But the hostname and network details will become available after the instance is created. Could you please suggest me a better way to capture that info and update it in user data?

Comment: Why do you need to set this? Also it might be worth showing a slightly expanded example where you show the Terraform code for creating your user data and also creating the instance with the user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the issue, so in case of network details, we can get hold of the network as below, and then extract the details about it such as cidr etc. For the host name however, we can specify the name in user data and the cloud-init will set the name for us.

```
   data "google_compute_subnetwork" "default-subnetwork" {
      project = "my-project"
      name   = "my-subnetwork"
      region = "us-central1"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- In case you have everything in one backend (you have one terraform state that manages everything), have you checked if any of the [output parameters of the gcp instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html#attributes-reference) is valid for your purpose? You can use them with a code snippet like in this examples:

`google_compute_instance.name_of_your_instance.network_interface.0.network_ip`

`google_compute_instance.name_of_your_instance.self_link`

- If you have the gcp instance in a terraform backend different from the one in which you use the user data, maybe you can retrieve the details with  `terraform_remote_state` (See more in https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html). The nice thing is that this remote state is read only so nothing you do with it can affect your gcp instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, it is close but I need to pass net-mask, network  , and broadcast details in user data as well. I extract that info from the cidr info I provided initially, but sometimes  the cidr is something like 172.16.10.0/25 but the cloud decided to create a network 172.16.8.0 and it breaks here. So trying to get the info from the actual network created.